# Passing pointers to the same address as function arguments

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, sequence-points

Suppose I have a weired add function which does an addition and an increment then stores the result to somewhere else.

```
void add(const int* a, const int* b, int* c) {
    *c = (*a)++ + *b;
}
```

If I pass the same pointer to a and c,

```
int a = 1, b = 3;
add(&a, &b, &a);
```

Then it will eventually modify the value pointed by `a`.

My questions:

1. Does this violate the const qualifier for the first argument?
2. Is the operation undefined as the typical unsequenced `x = x++` is?

I feel the answer to both questions should be YES, but my gcc gives a warning for neither.

EDIT: I know there can be a better workaround for the sake of the code. My question is more on the language feature itself.

Comment: Yes, the operation in your add function violates the const qualifier for the first argument.  You are attempting to modify the value pointed to by 'a' while also using its value in the expression??

Comment: I don't see a problem in this code. It does not violate the `const`, as you are not modifying the object pointed by `a`, even though it appears to be the same one that is pointed by a non-const pointer.  The object itself as passed isn't `const`. It also has no problem of unsequenced operation, as it is the pointer which is incremented and not the pointee. The `++` operation here has no effect at all.

Comment: `const` on a pointer only means that you will not modify the object through *that* pointer. It doesn't mean that the same object can't be modified through some other pointer.

Comment: This is why the `restrict` qualifier was created -- it's how you indicate that the argument pointers are not allowed to point to the same objects.

Comment: Did you mean `(*a)++` or `*(a++)`? Your code is equivalent to the latter, but you discuss it as if it's the former.

Comment: After the edit you have an unsequenced operation and thus UB.

Comment: How can you have `(*a)++` when you've declared `*a` to be `const`?

Comment: LOL. Your edit have inverted the answers to both of your questions.

Comment: Well the entire question became pointless because I'm stupid to confuse (*a)++ and *a++. Should be closed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the increment or `b` have to do with your question about `const`. Aren't you basically just asking if you can assign the same address to both a const and non-const pointer variable, then modify the object through the non-const pointer?

Comment: This question makes no sense as it will not compile, thus no program behaviour as it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```c
void add(const int* a, const int* b, int* c) {
    *c = (*a)++ + *b;
}
```

This doesn't compile.

```
<source>:2:14: error: increment of read-only location '*a'
    2 |     *c = (*a)++ + *b;
      |
```

We could remove the `const`.

```c
void add(int* a, const int* b, int* c) {
    *c = (*a)++ + *b;
}
```

But then we encounter undefined behaviour when `a == c || a == b`. We can signal this using the `restrict` keyword.

```c
void add(int* restrict a, const int* restrict b, int* restrict c) {
    *c = (*a)++ + *b;
}
```

With this signature, it becomes UB to call `add` with two identical arguments.

Comment: The 3 `restrict` also allows the compilation of `add()` to assume `a,b,c` do not overlap.  Thus potentially emitting faster code.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, Isn't that the case for this code even when `restrict` isn't used? Without `restrict`, it's UB when they do overlap, so any behaviour is acceptable when they do overlap, so the compiler can assume they don't overlap.

Comment: With no `restrict` and `a == c || a == b` is false,  `b == c` is OK, not UB.  I do not see optimization potential in this case, with or without `restrict`.  In general, using `restrict` can make for more efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Does this violate the const qualifier for the first argument?

Yes.

`(*a)` is an lvalue expression with type `const int`.  But

> The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator [...] shall be a modifiable lvalue.

(C17 6.5.2.4/1)

and

> A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that [...] does not have a const-qualified type [...]

(C17 6.3.2.1/1)

Thus, `(*a)++` expresses a modification that, because of `const`-qualification, violates language requirements.  I take this to be what you mean by "violate the const qualifier". The program has undefined behavior as a result.

That `*a` and `*c` are aliases does not enter into it, however.  This rule is based on the types of lvalues by which access is expressed, not the effective type of the objects to which they refer, so the assignment to `*c` is ok as far as these particular provisions are concerned.

---

> 2. Is the operation undefined as the typical unsequenced `x = x++` is?

Yes, in the particular function call presented.

The rule is:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
> a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
> computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
> undefined.

(C17 6.5/2)

Note in particular that this provision is given in terms of the objects that are accessed, not the lvalues through which the accesses are performed.

---

> my gcc gives a warning for neither

That's odd.

6.5.2.4/1 is a language constraint, so diagnosing violations is a conformance requirement on C implementations.  My GCC does diagnose this:

```
$ gcc -o ub -O2 ub.c
ub.c: In function ‘add’:
ub.c:3:14: error: increment of read-only location ‘*a’
     *c = (*a)++ + *b;
              ^~
```

Something is wrong if yours does not.

On the other hand, 6.5/2 is *not* a language constraint, and in practice, it may not be possible for the compiler to recognize the UB in such a case.  Implementations are not required to diagnose this.  I did not find any combination of options that elicited a diagnostic from GCC about this one.

Comment: It does not invoke UB as it will **not compile**. It has to compile and generate the executable to have any behaviour.

Comment: @gulpr, the language spec does not distinguish between UB at the translation (compilation) stage and UB at the execution stage.  Nor does it require that compilers reject the code in question.  The distinction you are trying to draw is not supported by the spec.

Comment: The behaviour of the program can be observed only when it is executed. Otherwise, there is no observable behaviour and the program can't invoke UB. Same as this program: https://godbolt.org/z/6v89xYT7z

Comment: Again, @gulpr. the spec's "undefined behavior" is that of the whole C implementation when processing the program, where "program" is defined as the C source.  That does include behavior during the translation stage, so **no**, a program does not need to be executed to have UB.

Comment: @gulpr: C 2018 3.4.3 2 notes “Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution…” So, yes, “undefined behavior” applies to behavior during translation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you misinterpreting it. It means that the way the translation is performed can be undefined (for example `int x = INT_MAX + 1;` or  `int x = 1 << (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT) ;`) and it is about similar circumstances, not source file which fails to compile.

Comment: @gulpr: (a) It says behavior during translation. (b) No, I am not misinterpreting it. Throughout the C standard, it specifies behaviors for compilers as well as executing programs and other aspects of a C implementation. For example, it routinely requires diagnostic messages for some things, which are behaviors of the translator (the compiler). (c) I elided the quote; it goes on to mention “to terminating a **translation** or execution…”, so it is definitely including translation.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this violate the const qualifier for the first argument?

It does and it will not compile (https://godbolt.org/z/Mfjf6bsMq), but no UB as there will be no executable to behave defined or undefined way. But if you modify your program to pass the reference to the `const` object

```
void add(int* a, const int* b, int* c) {
    *c = (*a)++ + *b;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int a = 5;
    int b = 3, c = 4;

    add(&a, &b, &c);
}
```

It will invoke **Undefined Behavior**.

> Is the operation undefined as the typical unsequenced x = x++ is?

It can only be undefined if you pass the reference to the same object:

```
void add(int* a, const int* b, int* c) {
    *c = (*a)++ + *b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int c = 4;

    add(&a, &a, &c);
}
```